# WMA support in Java

Tags: java, wma

Actually, we need to convert a WMA audio file into FLAC. But there's a lack of ways to convert WMA into more convenient formats. Can you recommend us a library, that can help us, or something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is [JAVE](http://www.sauronsoftware.it/projects/jave/):

> The JAVE (Java Audio Video Encoder) library is Java wrapper on the
>   ffmpeg project. Developers can take take advantage of JAVE to
>   transcode audio and video files from a format to another. In example
>   you can transcode an AVI file to a MPEG one, you can change a DivX
>   video stream into a (youtube like) Flash FLV one, you can convert a
>   WAV audio file to a MP3 or a Ogg Vorbis one, you can separate and
>   transcode audio and video tracks, you can resize videos, changing
>   their sizes and proportions and so on. Many other formats, containers
>   and operations are supported by JAVE.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's exactly what we were looking for!

Comment: @user1531851 You're welcome! and I am glad that I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

[MFSampledSP](http://www.tagtraum.com/mfsampledsp/index.html) supports WMA.
It's suitable for Windows 7 or later.